# UWP XAML: Filling the screen with 2 elements, one Viewbox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a grid with two elements, a scaling Viewbox and a Textblock. I want to have the Viewbox take only the space it needs, but also only the space it can get.

Images explain it much better, the desired image first:
[image: The way I want it to work]
However, when I resize my application to be wider, the Viewbox starts to overtake the Textblock below it:
[image: The Viewbox overtaking the Textblock]

Here's a dumbed down version of my XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="MainGrid" Margin="0" UseLayoutRounding="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Zulrah">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Blue" Width="150" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Red" Width="150" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TextOutput" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100">
        Hello world!
        <LineBreak />
        Life's good
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

You can more or less ignore the second column (with Width="0"), it's used for when the application becomes wide-screen (or landscape). It has the same issue:
[image: The same issue happens when entering 'portrait' mode]

In short: I want the TextBlock to obey it's MinHeight="100", while still maximizing the space the Viewbox uses.

PS: Please note that some settings make the Viewbox scale to a larger size than actually fits on the screen, this is not desireable!

**Edit:** Remarkably, setting a MinHeight="100" on the second row has no effect...

Comment: Setting fixed or percentages height for second row in MainGrid is not suitable for you?

Comment: Doing that results into wasted space like this: http://puu.sh/oXckj.png at certain window sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `ThemeResource` in your code, I think you are developing an UWP app as there is no `ThemeResource` in WPF. If so, please remove WPF in your title and tags as they are two different frameworks. Mixed use of UWP and WPF may cause confusion.

For UWP apps, in `Grid`, while setting row's height to **Auto**, the row will size to fit its content. After the Auto rows are calculated, the row which height is set to ***** will get part of the remaining height.

According to your description, you want the `TextBlock` to obey it's `MinHeight` and the `Viewbox` gets part of the remaining height. So you can change the `RowDefinitions` like following:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And to make the `Viewbox` fill the remaining area, we can set `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` to **`Stretch`**. Besides this, you may also need to set `Stretch` property to `Fill` to make the content in `Viewbox` resize to fill the destination dimensions.

The complete XAML code may like following:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid"
      Margin="0"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      UseLayoutRounding="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox x:Name="Zulrah"
             Grid.Row="0"
             AllowDrop="True"
             Stretch="Fill">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                       Width="150"
                       Height="250"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1"
                       Width="150"
                       Height="250"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                       Fill="Red" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextOutput"
               Grid.Row="1"
               MinWidth="100"
               MinHeight="100">
        Hello world!
        <LineBreak />
        Life's good
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Changing the first row from Auto to * results in a lot of unused space taken by the Viewbox (green in the image), what I want that space to be taken by the Textblock (Gold in the image). I only want the Viewbox to take part of the remaining height if it actually uses it. The Viewbox doesn't take more space than it needs with Auto, but then it doesn't obey the MinHeight. http://imgur.com/58jFwKe

Comment: @ManIkWeet, if you set first row's height to `Auto`, your `TextBlock`  actually does obey the `MinHeight`. If you use **Live Property Explorer**  to see the `RenderSize` of your `TextBlock`, its still `*x100` even though you can't see the `TextBlock` like [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dit1.png). The `TextBlock` did't show completely because the windows's height is not large enough. If you want the `Viewbox` doesn't take more space than it needs, you can try to set `StretchDirection="DownOnly"` in `Viewbox`.